# Issues with swapping dates using pyqt5 calendarpopup

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.10

I got two QDateEdit Objects in (for simplicity here) a QWidget. However I ran in an for me not fixable issue. In order to get my idea:

```
Qdate1 = datecheckin
Qdate2 = datecheckout
```

The QDateEdits should switch dates, `if checkin > checkout` . On top there should be some special treatments if both are equal. If I put the dates via numblock/keyboard the code works somewhat, but still not ideally.

HOWEVER:
If i use the CalendarPopup to select the dates: Unexpected behaviour. I can't even explain what's going on.

I tried disconnecting and reconnecting slots and using one change_method instead of two seperate ones (with partial).

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDateEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, Qt

class DateWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.dateCheckin = QDateEdit()
        self.dateCheckout = QDateEdit()
        self.dateCheckin.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.dateCheckout.setCalendarPopup(True)
        
        self.dateCheckin.dateChanged.connect(self.checkin_changed)
        self.dateCheckout.dateChanged.connect(self.checkout_changed)
        
        layout.addWidget(self.dateCheckin)
        layout.addWidget(self.dateCheckout)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
    def checkin_changed(self, checkin):
        checkout = self.dateCheckout.date()
        if checkin > checkout:
            self.dateCheckin.setDate(checkout)
            self.dateCheckout.setDate(checkin)
        elif checkin == checkout:
            if checkout == QDate(1752, 9, 14):
                self.dateCheckout.setDate(checkout.addDays(1))
            else:
                self.dateCheckin.setDate(checkin.addDays(-1))
                
    def checkout_changed(self, checkout):
        checkin = self.dateCheckin.date()
        if checkout < checkin:
            self.dateCheckout.setDate(checkin)
            self.dateCheckin.setDate(checkout)
        elif checkout == checkin:
            if checkin == QDate(9999, 12, 31):
                self.dateCheckin.setDate(checkin.addDays(-1))
            else:
                self.dateCheckout.setDate(checkout.addDays(1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DateWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Im using python 3.10.13 and pyqt5 5.15.9 (can't upgrade python cause other reasons)

Edit:
The "magic dates" i filter for are the max and min dates that qt designer shows for the QDateEdits. The idea behind their implementation was to workaround possible "lower then the lowest date and vise versa issues/possible errors"

Edit2:
Here an code example, where at least the swap works correctly for numpad input (but not calendarpopup). I hope you get my confusion:
Setting checkin > checkout by numpad vs by calendarpopup.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDateEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

class DateWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.checkin_date = QDateEdit()
        self.checkout_date = QDateEdit()
        self.checkin_date.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.checkout_date.setCalendarPopup(True)
        
        self.checkin_date.dateChanged.connect(self.check_and_swap_dates)
        self.checkout_date.dateChanged.connect(self.check_and_swap_dates)
        
        layout.addWidget(self.checkin_date)
        layout.addWidget(self.checkout_date)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
    def check_and_swap_dates(self):
        checkin = self.checkin_date.date()
        checkout = self.checkout_date.date()
        
        if checkin > checkout:
            self.checkin_date.setDate(checkout)
            self.checkout_date.setDate(checkin)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DateWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QDateTimeEdit widget is possibly one of the most complex in the standard Qt widget library, and, along with QAbstractSpinBox based widgets, its complexity makes it a bit ugly to work with.

In this case, the issue is caused by the internal interactions of the QCalendarWidget (the popup) with the QDateTimeEdit widget.

The calendar is actually shown in a parent container (similarly to what QComboBox does for its item view) that adds further complexity to event handling that can cause further delayed signals and events, and such increased complexity is augmented by the fact that by doing `setDate()` you implicitly cause **at least** one `dateChange` signal on the target widget, which will call again the connected function.

This is not a terrible problem for simpler widgets, since almost all Qt objects ignore attempts to change property values that do not result in actual changes: if the new value is identical to the current, nothing happens, and if a signal notifier for that property exists, it will not be emitted.

In this case, though, the above mentioned complexities makes things worse, because you're attempting to access properties of *two* different widgets, with both having a signal notifier for the same property call the same function. The presence of another widget (the calendar popup) adds a bit of madness into the mix.

What actually happens is that calling `setDate()` with a different date in a function connected to the `dateChanged` signal of *one* QDateTimeEdit, will result in internally setting the date *at least twice* when the date is set from the calendar widget.

Try to change the connected function to the following, and you'll see that it will be called *twice* when editing the spinbox (using arrow keys or by typing a new date), and *four times* when using the calendar widget:

```py
    def check_and_swap_dates(self):
        checkin = self.checkin_date.date()
        checkout = self.checkout_date.date()

        if checkin > checkout:
            print('attempting to fix the date', checkin.toString())
            self.checkin_date.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
```

Note the output of the `print()` function: the first time the date is the *new* date, while the second is the *previous* one; when using the calendar widget, you'll get a repeated result.

Even blocking signals through `widget.blockSignals(True)` or QSignalBlocker doesn't suffice, since the second signal will be emitted *later*. With the following code, the signal will still be emitted *twice* when using the calendar widget:

```py
    def check_and_swap_dates(self):
        checkin = self.checkin_date.date()
        checkout = self.checkout_date.date()

        if checkin > checkout:
            print('attempting to fix the date', checkin.toString())
            with QSignalBlocker(self.checkin_date):
                self.checkin_date.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
```

When attempting to change *both* widgets, things get tricky: when the first signal is emitted, the `checkin` is greater, so we swap dates, but this causes the `checkout` to correspond to the `checkin`; when the signal is emitted again, the `checkout` is now the old `checkin` and equal to the "wrong" `checkin`, so the checkin widget doesn't get restored because the `checkin > checkout` condition isn't met anymore.

Considering the above, we need to split things in two parts:

1. update the *sender* (the widget that emitted the signal) ensuring that further changes are not emitted unnecessarily;
2. *delay* the update of the other widget;

```py
    def check_and_swap_dates(self):
        checkin = self.checkin_date.date()
        checkout = self.checkout_date.date()

        if checkin > checkout:
            if self.sender() == self.checkin_date:
                with QSignalBlocker(self.checkin_date):
                    self.checkin_date.setDate(checkout)
                targetWidget = self.checkout_date
                targetDate = checkin
            else:
                with QSignalBlocker(self.checkout_date):
                    self.checkout_date.setDate(checkin)
                targetWidget = self.checkin_date
                targetDate = checkout

            def updateTarget():
                targetWidget.setDate(targetDate)
                targetWidget.setFocus()

            QTimer.singleShot(0, updateTarget)
```

Finally, an important suggestion about UX. As you probably noted, I added a `setFocus()` call on the "swapped" widget, which is important to let the user know that something has changed.

In reality, though, all this is not a good idea: when editing "logically ordered" fields, that order should be maintained, even considering the input focus and the context of each field. If the user edits the start date, we should assume that *that* is the date reference they want to change, so we either prevent entering invalid input (eg. a start date limits the `minimumDate()` of the end date), or we update the related field (set the end date equal to the start if it's greater).

The former approach can be sometimes ideal, but can also make things awkward: if the user selected a date range of a week and wants to change the start to the next week, they will need do things in the opposite way: first change the end date, then the start one.
The latter is usually better, but doesn't consider a previously date range: considering the case above; a possible further approach could consider previous date range (before the change) and eventually update the target date by shifting by the source date with range.

Comment: Well, it works. A short explanation why `QTimer.singleShot(0, updateTarget)` + setup is needed and why the simple statement `self.checkout_date.setDate(checkin)` / `self.checkin_date.setDate(checkout)` doesn't work instead would be nice.

Comment: Also why additional `with QSignalBlocker(self.checkin_date):
                    self.checkin_date.setDate(checkout)` blocks doesn't work. I'm a bit confused. 
`with QSignalBlocker(` ensures that the calenderPopup won't inject double calls and
`QTimer.singleShot(0, updateTarget)` delays the change even so its `0`? But why must it be delayed?

Comment: It's already explained: due to some internal interaction between the QDateTimeEdit and the popup, calling `setDate()` with a different date than what received from the same widget will cause a further `dateChanged()` signal that is emitted *later*, so it can't be prevented with QSignalBlocker and the other widget change must be "scheduled" for the next cycle of the event loop. I cannot explain to you the *exact* reason behind the doubled signal, as said, QAbstractSpinBox is a weird class, and the related QDateTimeEdit is even worse, with dozen of interconnected private functions and signals.

Comment: The only way to know the real cause is to go through the full code of those classes; I'm fairly used to Qt sources, but the complexity of those classes is high and, frankly, I won't spend *that much time* to study the C++ sources for somebody else: you can see that for yourself, by looking up the code of QAbstractSpinBox (including the internal QAbstractSpinBoxPrivate), QDateTimeEdit, its internal QCalendarPopup (the container of the calendar), QCalendarWidget and, probably, part of the interaction with QAbstractItemView (the QTableView showing dates), which may be a possible culprit.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding why it works. For example, it seems to work without the `with QSignalBlocker(self.checkout_date)` statements. Nonetheless:  
The "with" statements halve the method/slot calls, regardless of the input chosen. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I guess the halving comes from the fact that the `self.checkout_date.setDate(checkin)` would otherwise emit a another one.

Comment: The signal blocker for the sender prevents the double signal as explained above. The one delayed for the target prevents partial "unrelated" recursion. Consider A and B as your QDateTimeEdits: 1. user changes A to `d1`, which is greater than the date of B, `d2`; 2. `dateChanged` is triggered and switches `d2` to A and `d1` to B; 3. *after* that, another `dateChanged` signal is emitted from A (due to the unknown reasons above), but using the old `d1` date set by the previous signal (ignoring the new `setDate()`); 4. at that point B already has its date set as `d1` as above, so the further »

Comment: » `if checkin > checkout` comparison will not be met, and the `A.setDate()` that would eventually *fix again* the date will never be called again as it should. The result is that then both A and B will have the same date; the same also happens when doing the opposite (setting a date for B that is less than that of A). I know, it's a bit complex to figure it out, and that's why we should always ensure that a function triggered by a changed property that could then change that property again is always triggered **only** when the value actually changes. Recursion is always around the corner ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed with the following new slot setup:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDateEdit, QFormLayout, QLabel, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

class DateWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()

        label1 = QLabel("Checkin:")
        label2 = QLabel("Checkout:")
        
        self.datecheckin = QDateEdit(calendarPopup=True)
        self.datecheckout = QDateEdit(calendarPopup=True)
        
        self.datecheckin.editingFinished.connect(self.check_and_swap_dates)
        self.datecheckout.editingFinished.connect(self.check_and_swap_dates)

        self.datecheckin.calendarWidget().clicked.connect(self.check_and_swap_dates)
        self.datecheckout.calendarWidget().clicked.connect(self.check_and_swap_dates)

        
        layout.addRow(label1, self.datecheckin)
        layout.addRow(label2, self.datecheckout)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
    def check_and_swap_dates(self):
        checkin = self.datecheckin.date()
        checkout = self.datecheckout.date()
        
        if checkin > checkout:
            self.datecheckin.setDate(checkout)
            self.datecheckout.setDate(checkin)
        elif checkin == checkout:
            if checkout == QDate(9999, 12, 31):
                self.datecheckin.setDate(checkin.addDays(-1))
            else:
                self.datecheckout.setDate(checkout.addDays(1))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DateWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My previous implementation of `datechanged` was causing the malfunctions of the calendarPopup.
By changing `datechanged` to the `editingFinished` slot I solved the initial issue with one (major) downside:

The user had to confirm the date (regardless if input by keyboard or by calendarPopup) with the 'enter' key.

The solution:
Adding additional`calendarWidget().clicked.connect` slots.
With this setup, the 'calenderPopup' works as desired. If the date is not entered via 'calenderPopup' but via the keyboard, it still has to be confirmed with the 'enter' key. This is not ideal but reasonably acceptable.